# Ubuntu server (postfix) mismatch of version apt-get install and apt-get source

Tags: apt, postfix

I tried to apply VDA patch to postfix, but I see that my installed version is 2.9.6 installed via apt-get install. While when I try to get source apt-get source, it gave me 2.9.1.

So what is happening here?

[image]

Comment: Any progress? : )

Comment: @AndersF.U.Kiær yep figured it out myself :) Wouldn't image postfix 2.9 would live in security repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lacking a entry in your apt sourcelist. (NB. I use a mirror)

`deb-src http://archive.mirror.blix.eu/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted`